# SQL Fetching values with special characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I got an Employee schema in oracle 11g.

Emp_ID,Emp_Name and SALARY.

Need to return values inserting special characters.

eg. `2**SAM**24000`

Is there a way to return values w/o using INSERT statement and hence not permanently changing the table contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to concatenate several columns with a `'**'` delimiter separating the column values:

```
SELECT Emp_ID || '**' || Emp_Name || '**' || Salary
FROM   Employee
```